# ZipOutputStream FTPClient

Tags: zipoutputstream

```
FTPClient ftpClient;

ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;   
zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(ftpClient.storeFileStream("a.zip")); 

String str;
byte []conarr=str.getBytes();

zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("1.txt")); 
zipOut.write(conarr);
zipOut.close();
```

If `str` only has several characters, it's ok,
but if `str` is dozens of kB, the zip file has an error.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're populating `str`. Also, you should almost *certainly* not be using `getBytes()` without an encoding. It's entirely possible that you shouldn't be using a string at all. Please edit your code to show a *complete* method, as well as explaining what you're trying to do and *exactly* what goes wrong. Oh, and look at the formatting help.

Comment: What language is this? Please edit your question to include the correct language tag.